# Reading nested configuration section element of same type from web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config, configuration-management

Ok this is a tricky one or I just don't know how to do it.

I have to problem creating and reading custom config sections like:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c/>
  <c/>
 </b>
</a>
```

The issue I am having is reading the below configuration with ConfigurationManager.GetSection("a"):

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
   <c/>
  <c>
 </b>
</a>
```

Is there a way to get this working?

thank you.

Comment: That's not valid XML you have there. Any typos?

Comment: nope it was intended that way.

Comment: The second snippet isn't valid XML. It won't parse no matter how hard you try. You've got an open <c> tag there. Also nesting a <c /> tag inside of  <c> </c> so you get <c><c /></c> is awfully hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

My advice? Ditch configuration manager and load the config into an XDocument. Say you have a config file shown below:

```
<Settings>
    <ApplicationSettings>
        <AppSetting1 Value="Test1" />
        <AppSetting2 Value="Test2" />
    </ApplicationSettings>
    <DeviceSettings>
        <DeviceSetting1 Value="Test3" />
        <DeviceSetting2 Value="Test4" />
    </DeviceSettings>
</Settings>
```

To get a value from it you can load the config into an XDocument:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"Path\to\file.xml");
```

Then:

```
String test1 = xdoc.Element("Settings").Element("ApplicationSettings").Element("Appsetting1").Attribute("Name").Value;
```